# parsing dictionaries with nested list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, dictionary

I have the following response back from a server and I need to parse it in my JavaScript. I'm a little lost on how to correctly go about this.

```
{
  "Applications": [
    {
      "Application": "jackbob",
      "ExceptionPeriod": "04/04/2017 - 05/06/2017",
      "InstanceIds": [
        {
          "Name": "Bob",
          "InstanceId": "i-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Jack",
          "InstanceId": "i-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'll post below what I currently have.

```
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        for (var key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var value = data[key];
                for (var k in value) {
                    var value2 = value[k];
                    for (var l in value2) {
                        console.log(value2[l]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by you need to parse it? Are you having trouble getting a specific value?

Comment: What I mean by parse it is the goal is for every dictionary "application" I'm going to display the contents in a webpage. So it would basically be like placing the values into a table to display on the client